# What Race of Beings live on the Planet Terminus?

Tags: star-wars

I'm trying to write a Star Wars story in which Terminus attacks a planet that I've made up and I need to know what kind of beings live on the planet. Terminus is an Outer-Rim planet.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your question, but perhaps you could provide more information: where (as in, in what Star Wars work) is Terminus mentioned? What do you know about the planet other than its general location and name?

Comment: @Martha Well, I didn't know anything about Terminus until I found a map of the Star Wars galaxy and found it in the Outer Rim, then I began the research but found no info on it about its races

Comment: This is the only info I could find http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Terminus

Comment: OK, so put that in your question: "I found this planet name on a map of the Star Wars galaxy published in [insert info here], but other than the name and location, it doesn't give any further details." Or something like that.

Comment: Perhaps the Terminals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I have found.

> It was a heavily trafficked shipping center at the edge of the galaxy,
>   not far from the Red Nebula. It sat at the intersection of the
>   Corellian Trade Spine and Hydian Way. The skies of Terminus were
>   filled with bizarre ships hailing from Wild Space and the Unknown
>   Regions.
>
> Terminus' name and its position as a crucial socioeconomic center at
>   the edge of the galaxy strongly suggest that it is a reference to the
>   planet of the same name that gave rise to a renewed galaxy-spanning
>   empire in Isaac Asimov's Foundation novel series. Furthermore,
>   Asimov's city-planet and one-time galactic capital of Trantor was a
>   partial inspiration for Coruscant.

Source: [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Terminus)

It appears to be merely a tribute to Isaac Asimov's Foundation series, so I'd be surprised if there was a particularly well developed background story for this planet.

As a side note, I don't think it is a very good idea to write a Star Wars story featuring a planet which was already imported from another universe, especially if you do not intend to write a crossover. But that's just my own opinion.